# Wampserver is not installing correctly

Tags: wamp

I am trying to install Wampserver3 addon PHP 7.0.13 on my computer. Every time I attempt the installation I get the following error:

> The installation folder chosen (%1) is not that of the Wampserver.
>   Select the installation folder of Wampserver

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Download the 32bit instead of the 64bit. I had a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You were trying to install an ADDON. An addon will, like the name suggests only add to an existing install of WAMPServer

Install a full release of WAMPServer 32bit or 64bit whichever you like and then attempt to upgrade individual components.

Current [latest release](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/)

Alternatively, you incorrectly specified the location of the existing WAMPServer install.

Answer (score 0):

In short: add `/dir=<wampdir>` to the addon install command line.

Longer: If you are intentionally installing the php addon as you say in your question, I assume you already have the current version of the base wampserver installed.

To install the addon when you get a "select installation folder" error message, add `/dir=<wamp-dir>` to the command line when you execute the addon installer. (for example with today's php 7.3 addon and with a 64bit wamp installed in c:\wamp.)

```
wampserver3_x64_addon_php7.3.10.exe /dir=c:\wamp
```

The `/dir=<wampdir>` argument also works for other addons such as the apache, mysql and mariadb addons.

Why you would want to do this: Addons let you use a different or more current version of apache, mariadb, mysql or php than the default wamp install. The addon installs that are available from SourceForge at https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/ help you avoid intricate and fragile changes to .ini files and the wamp directory tree.

Answer (score 0):

The wamp server should be running, that way addon instalator will find the target directory, where the addon should be installed